# jQuery - Getting class of an element through the event.target property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I have the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $("*").click(function(event){
         var x = event.target;

         if (x.nodeName == "DIV"){                  
           alert(x.attr("class"));
         }

       })
    </script>
```

This throws an 'undefined' exception... Is there any other way to get the class of an element which triggered the 'click' event? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that you don't have to refer to `event.target`, but you might as well just refer to `this`. `if (this.nodeName == "DIV") alert( $(this).attr("class"));`

Comment: Well, using $('*') as selector, you shoud use event.stopPropagation() in your event callback function, just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery offers some syntactic sugar to help with your check - [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) allows you to validate an element against any other valid selector:

```
var $target = event.target;
if ($target.is('div')){
  alert($target.attr('class'));
}
```

There are some further changes to consider:

- `.click(handler)` is explicitly assigned to the matching elements (every single element in your case). This adds overhead; also the handler will not apply to any element added dynamically *after* the handler assignment is executed. Instead, *delegate* the handler by using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- refactor your logic so that instead of handling every single click and validating it you could make it applicable only to divs in the first place by changing the selector to `$('div')`
- rely on `this` which is pretty much the convention

After all these changes the code becomes smaller and more readable:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Answer (score 13):

`event.target` is a DOM object. So to use jQuery methods you have to convert it to jQuery object:

```
alert($(x).attr("class"));
```

Otherwise, you may use property [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className) to get the class of the element:

```
alert(x.className);
```

BTW, in your example you may simply use `this` keyword instead of `event.target`.